# Craft CMS, Amazon EC2 & Load balancers

Tags: aws, load-balancer

I am looking for a simple solution & if possible resources on how to go about getting Craft CMS setup behind a load balancer. Craft CMS is going to be hosted on AWS EC2 instance, I have MySQL on a different instance. I have read about setting up and using shared storage variables but I haven't really found a way to setup a shared storage. Anyone has any idea on where to begin?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if anything on AWS can be considered simple, but there is a good writeup on getting Craft up and running with EC2: https://solspace.com/blog/spinning-up-a-craft-cms-development-site-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: Brad - The solution I looking for is to create a shared storage between 2 CraftCMS installations. I have read about this [link](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4719/load-balancing-nodes-configuration-3-craft-nodes-behind-f5-big-ip) but I have to think about transitioning to Azure next year (we are changing from AWS to Auzre) and don't want to change paths when that happens (images, documents,etc).