# Do servers in a multi-server Craft setup need to share a storage directory?

Tags: config, server

We have a multi-server Craft setup, for redundancy and scaling.

We've been using an shared NFS drive to to host Craft's storage directory, by setting `CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH` to a mounted `/craft-data/` directory on each machine.

in `public/index.php`:

```
define('CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH', '/craft-data/');
```

One reason it was important to do this was to let Craft share sessions across machines, because they were stored on the filesystem.

Recently, we transitioned from saving our sessions in the filesystem to saving them in redis.

If we can, I'd like to abandon the NFS drive altogether and let each machine have its own `/craft-data/` directory, since we no longer need to maintain this shared filesystem for session sharing.

Looking at the contents of the craft `/runtime/` directory, we see several subdirectories that seem like they could contain important shared state, such as `cache` and `state`:

`$ pwd && ls -l
/craft-data/runtime
total 16
drwxrwxr-x   5 craft_user users   45 Jan 19 16:12 assets
drwxrwxr-x   2 craft_user users   49 Jan 26 09:34 cache
drwxrwxr-x 100 craft_user users 4096 Jan 26 09:37 compiled_templates
drwxr-xr-x   2 craft_user users   65 Jan 25 12:12 CSS
drwxr-xr-x   2 craft_user users   65 Jan 25 12:00 HTML
drwxrwxr-x   2 craft_user users 4096 Jan 19 16:12 logs
drwxrwxr-x   2 craft_user users 4096 Jan 26 08:52 sessions
drwxrwxr-x   2 craft_user users   22 Nov 16 14:55 state
drwxrwxr-x   2 craft_user users 4096 Jan 25 15:17 temp
drwxr-xr-x   2 craft_user users   65 Dec 14 11:27 URI`

Do any of these directories need to be shared, in a multi-server setup? Is it safe for us to stop using a networked filesystem, for the `CRAFT_STORAGE_PATH`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd [lean towards](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4729/57) keeping the shared NFS volume.  It's not just the runtime folder, but things like backups, site logos, user avatars, etc. and anything else plugins might be storing in storage that you'd want to consider as well.